# My SqlQuery is returning the last result rather than the first

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have produced a SQLQuery to return the first result, but instead the query seems to return the last.

Code below:

```
   public ActionResult Location()
   {
       List<string> name;
       using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
       {
           name =
               dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<String>(
                   String.Format("select distinct (locations.Code) from locations LIMIT 1")).ToList();
       };
       return(name[0]);
    }
```

Name seems to be equal to the last item rather than the first

Comment: You can delete your question...

Comment: Stackoverflow only seems to allow you to post one question per hour, so didn't want it to have to wait that long

Comment: name.last() should do the trick

Comment: When I do that, it's still equal to the last value. It's as though the arrary is acting like a string and simply overwriting a single value

Comment: You select the code field of the locations table (or view) but you limit it to one single record. Records in sql are not sorted so the database is free to decide which record should be returned in which order. To specify your desired order, you should add "ORDER BY" to your select statement, as @AlexK. already told you.

Comment: What is *last*? The last record you are seeing directly in your database table? How is that table *ordered*? By some specific *column*, by *primary key*, you don't know, etc.? In order to get the same last element, add an `ORDER` clause to your SQL query consistent with your notion of *first* and *last* (if the order is by *primary key* this should not be necesary).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Identity key such as "Id", you could add an "`ORDER BY Id DESC`" in your query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (locations.Code) FROM locations ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1
```

OR

Change your query to :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (locations.Code) FROM locations
```

And change the line :
"`return(name[0]);`"
to
"`return name.LastOrDefault();`"
using `System.Linq` of course

Comment: The table does not have a key id. Also, the items within it, are ordered by the time entered into the table

Comment: @Decepticon - "items within it, are ordered by the time entered into the table" -- see my other comment, no they're not.

Comment: Then ORDER BY Date DESC

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no "`ORDER BY`" clause the "`order`" in which the records are fetched is considered "`undefined`." (It's probably deterministic, but the point is...don't count on it.)  As Alex K said, add an ORDER BY.